# Decompose a Riesz measure with atom into atom free and sum of Dirac measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a Riesz measure with some atom on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show there exists two Riesz measure $\lambda$ and $\rho$ satisfying $\mu=\lambda+\rho$ where $\lambda$ has no atoms and $$\rho=\sum_{k=1}\alpha_k\delta_{x_k},$$ where $x_k\in\mathbb{R}^n,\alpha\in(0,\infty)$, and $1\le k \le N, N\in[1,\infty]$

**PS**: By Riesz measure, I mean the measure associated with a positive linear functionals on $C_c(X)$ on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ using [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem)

**My try**

Currently I have proved that by Lebesgue decomposition of $\mu$ with respect to $\mathcal{L}^n$, the Lebesgue measure, I can decompose $\mu=\mu_1+\mu_2$, where $\mu_1\ll\mathcal{L}^n,\mu_2\perp \mathcal{L}^n$, then further restrict $\mu_2$ to the countable atom $C$ (i.e. $\lambda_1$) and its complement ( i.e. $\rho$), I decompose $\mu$ into atom-free part ($\mu_1+\lambda_1$) and purely atomic part ($\rho$).

Then the question left is how to show they are both Riesz measure.

Comment: What is a Riesz measure? Also, clearly $\lambda = \mu-\rho$, so since $\rho$ is purely atomic measure, it must contain all the atoms of $\mu$. Definition of Riesz measure would thus clarify it a bit.

Comment: @Ilya Sorry. I thought it's a commonly used terminology. I have mean the measure associated with a positive linear functionals on $C_c(X)$ on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ using Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: @Ilya I have managed to make some progress. May you please look at my editing and give me some hints about how to solve the question?

Comment: What about singular continuous part?

Comment: @Ilya Yes. The singular part is sum of Dirac measure, each one is associated with positive linear functional $\Lambda f=f(x_i)$. How about the absolute continuous part?

Comment: You've seen this [refined result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem)?

Comment: @Ilya Thanks for your reference. I just read it, but I don't quite understand how to apply it to solve my problem. May you elaborate it as an answer? About how to deal with the absolute continuous part and singular continuous part?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, from the link you've provided it follows that the Riesz measure is just a regular measure, so in particular it is $\sigma$-finite. For the latter reason, $\mu$ has countably many atoms, let them be a separate measure $\rho$. Define $\lambda = \mu-\rho$: clearly it does not have atoms, so you only need to show that $\lambda $ is regular (regularity of $\rho$ shall be a trivial task). Note also that if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite, then it may have uncountably many atoms.